# Inquiry on an integration problem

Tags: integration

Let $f,g$ be some differentiable functions of $x$ that satisfy $fg \neq 0$ and $a,b$ be some positive real numbers. Can the following integral equality

$$Im \int_1^\infty f(x)\cos^{2} \Bigg (\frac{(a+bi)g(x)}{2n}\Bigg) \mathrm {d}x = 0$$
                                                                                                     Hold for every positive integer $n$ with $ab\neq 0$?

EDIT: $f$ and $g$ are real valued and nonconstant.

Comment: If $g(x)=a-bi$ and $f=1$ then what happen?

Comment: Is the question "do there exist functions f,g and constants a,b (with conditions) s.t he following expression is 0 for every n"? Why is the question interesting? Remark: it will simplify the matter if you replace the complex expression above by a real one (this is easy to do).